# Override properties for specific test class

Tags: testing, quarkus

Is it possible to override properties just for one test class? I already have a specific application.properties for tests and I would like to override some of them just for this one test class. Somthing similar like `@SpringBootTest(properties = {"myprop1=0, myprop2=hello"})` in Spring? Or is it possible to set a profile on class level? `@Profle("myProflileJustForThisTestClass") MyTestClass {...}`

Best
Boban

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing you can override properties like code below, getConfigOverrides() does what you have asked.

```java
package org.acme.getting.started.testing;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestProfile;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestProfile.TestResourceEntry;

public class MockGreetingProfile implements QuarkusTestProfile {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getConfigOverrides() { 
        return Collections.singletonMap("quarkus.resteasy.path","/api");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getEnabledAlternatives() { 
        return Collections.singleton(MockGreetingService.class);
    }


    @Override
    public String getConfigProfile() { 
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public List<TestResourceEntry> testResources() { 
        return Collections.singletonList(new TestResourceEntry(CustomWireMockServerManager.class));
    }
}
```